# <input type="file" name="image" value=""> 画像の保持について

Tags: php, html

formの中で `<input type="file" name="image" value="">` を書いてあります。

submit押下で、他inputタグが未入力の場合に、submit押下前に選択した画像ファイルを、次の画面で再度表示したいのですが、どなたかご存じでしたらご教示ください。

お手数をおかけしますがどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

まず、`input[type=file]` 上に事前に(自動的に)ファイルを選択させることは理論上不可能ではないですが、現実的ではなく無駄しかないのでお勧めしません。
(フォーム入力時に選択されたファイルのblobをJavaScriptで何らかの形で保持し、遷移後にJavaScriptで逆手順を行います)

別のわかりやすい手段の例としては、

- アップロードされたデータをセッションに一時的に保持し、再度ファイルが選択された場合にはそれを上書きする
- アップロードされたファイルについてDBにレコードを作成し、IDをフォームに保持する、以下同じ

  - この場合はほかのファイルにすり替えられないように対策が必要
- そもそも検証をJavaScriptやHTMLの機能で行い、できるだけ遷移を不要にする

  - もちろんサーバー側でのチェックは必要

などが考えられます。

Comment: そうなのですね、とっても詳しく説明いただき、感謝します。
ありがとうございます。
あまりよろしくないのだということがわかりました。
本当にありがとうございました。